# How do I enable mysqli on Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp, mamp

I am trying to enable mysqli on Mac OS X. I am using MAMP and I have tried XAMPP (I am open to either), but when I open the php.ini file and search for anything containing the word "mysqli" nothing is found, and when I try to run a PHP script containing any mysqli code, nothing happens: no errors are output, the script just fails to execute.

When I try to connect by

```
$dbh = new mysqli("localhost","root","root");
```

and I dump the variable `$dbh` it outputs:

```
object(mysqli)#1 (17) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=> string(5) "5.5.9" ["client_version"]=> int(50509) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(5) "5.5.9" ["server_version"]=> int(50509) ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(12) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }
```

This is the code I tried:

```
$dbh = new mysqli("localhost","root","root");
$dbh->select_db("php");
$dbh->query("SELECT * FROM test");
$count = $dbh->num_rows;
var_dump($count);
```

and the output is

```
NULL
```

Comment: what version of php, mam, xampp are you using? (also check phpinfo)

Comment: 5.3.6 , in which i was under the impression that it was compiled with that version of php, and when i search for "mysqli" when displaying phpinfo() it states that mysqli is enabled.

Comment: so would there be something causing these scripts to not run, they do not seem to produce any error messages, but any php scripts are not run afterwards.

Comment: Can you post a small script that fails?

Comment: i cant even connect for example: $dbh = new mysqli("localhost","root","root","php"); no php scripts will run afterwards, and if i try to just query a database, nothing happens, nothing show at all. check the edit please, thanks for the help and sticking around

Comment: Can you post the full script you are running?  connect_errno is 0 so it looks like it connected properly.  Now try to select a database `$dbh->select_db("database_name")` and then run some simple select statement `$dbh->query("select * from some_table")` and see that `$dbh->num_rows` is positive

Comment: everyone eventually gives up on me, and i get screwed :(

Comment: @mcbeav let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2455/discussion-between-foo-bah-and-mcbeav)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that mysqli is enabled:

Write the following to a php file in your web directory (I'm using native php, so I put it in /Library/WebServer/Documents/):

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Then check the output for the word "mysqli"

Comment: what did you put in that directory?

Comment: The native webserver in OSX uses apache, and the DocumentRoot is set to `/Library/WebServer/Documents`

Comment: yeah, it outputs that mysqli is enabled, but the scripts fail to run.

Answer (score 3):

If you still cannot connect:

Try using hostname `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

Mysql won't let me connect with localhost unless host is `%` (I know this is a hack)

I don't know the reason yet, 
but I will update my answer as soon as I find it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to stored the result in to MySQLi_Result class. Otherwise, you can use `affected_rows` variable to show the similar effect.

```
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM test");
$count = $result->num_rows;
$count = $dbh->affected_rows;
```

Comment: this is not working, i cant seem to get anything working, normal mysql queries work, but mysqli and mysqli prepared statements do not work.

Comment: Interesting. I've tested in my Mac and it worked (default PHP/Apache. I've installed MySQL). See if your mysql.sock is configured correctly in php.ini.

Comment: it says that it is enabled, what should the configuration be?

Comment: mysqli.default_socket
See if you have the socket file exists in the file system.